# Setting a Stash variable within an old style EE conditional

Tags: stash, conditionals, parse-order, ifelse

I'm working on an old EE site (v2.5.2) which for reasons I won't go into I cannot update to a newer version.

I am trying to set a Stash variable based on whether or not a condition evaluates to true. But, because of the way this version of EE handles conditionals the Stash variable is always being set regardless of the actual condition.

Simplified code snippet:

```
{exp:stash:set_value name="sample" value="no"}

-- loop starts here --
{if entry_id==''}
    {exp:stash:set_value name="sample" value="yes"}
    Other stuff here
{if:else}
    Other stuff here
{/if}
-- loop ends here --
```

No matter whether entry_id is empty or not, the Stash variable always shows as "yes".

I've tried using Switchee and If:else but have had absolutely no luck getting this apparently simple thing to work.

How can I get around this? It's driving me nuts.

Real code snippet (using Cartthrob's cart_items_info loop) and following information found at https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/switchee/viewthread/6566

```
{exp:stash:set parse_conditionals="true" parse_tags="yes" process="start"}
    {exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
        {exp:switchee variable="{item_options:sample}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="true"}
                {stash:sample}yes{/stash:sample}
            {/case}

            {case default="yes"}
                {!-- nothing going on here --}
            {/case}
        {/exp:switchee}
    {/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:get name="sample"}
```

That loop will output the correct information based on the value of {item_options:sample}. But the Stash variable is ALWAYS set to "yes" no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas you might want to try:

Use exp:stash:parse to make it parse the value at the end of the template https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp:stash:parse%7D

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
{exp:stash:get name="sample"}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Use `{embed="..." sample="{exp:stash:sample}"}` this always gets parsed at the end.

Wrap {exp:stash:set} around those tags like this:

```
{exp:stash:set name="sample" parse_conditionals="true" parse_tags="yes" process="start" parse_depth="4"}
    {exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
        {exp:switchee variable="{item_options:sample}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="true"}
                yes
            {/case}

            {case default="yes"}
               no
            {/case}
        {/exp:switchee}
    {/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:get name="sample"}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the variable on getting instead?

```
{exp:stash:set 
    name="sample" 
    parse_tags="yes" 
}{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}{item_options:sample}{/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}{/exp:stash:set}


{exp:stash:get name="sample"}

{!--or:--}
{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="sample"}}
    Do something
{/if}

{!--or possibly:--}
{if sample}
    Do something
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to get this working but I'm not sure why it now does.

```
    {exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
        {exp:switchee variable="{item_options:sample}" parse="inward"}
            {case value="true"}
                {exp:stash:set name="sample" output="no"}yes{/exp:stash:set}
            {/case}

            {case default="yes"}

            {/case}
        {/exp:switchee}
    {/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
```

I'm sure this isn't the best way but I've lost so much time on this that I'm moving on to something else.